# AWS Lambda can't find dependent library

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

This is my first time deploying to AWS Lambda and am getting a little stuck.

I have a large maven project called `Helpers` which has many submodules, many of them dependent on each other. In there I have one Helper called `Alerts`. I have a parent directory and everything builds and compiles successfully. So, that's good.

In Alerts there's a class called `PaymentAlerts` which has the line

`import com.mywebsite.messages.Doers`

where messages.Doers is found in the dependencies.

But, when I do a `mvn package` on the whole project and I find `alerts-1.0.jar` and upload it to AWS Lambda and I set my handler as `com.mywebsite.alerts.PaymentAlerts::doAlert` I get the following error:

> {
>
> com.mywebsite.alerts.PaymentAlerts: com/mywebsite/messaging/Doers",
>
> "errorType": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"
>
> "errorMessage": "Error loading class
>   }

How do I reconfigure this so that it finds all the necessary files?

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> AWS Lambda can't find dependent library

Except mvn, you can do with simple library dependency by putting all jars in one, Where your **MANIFEST** file contains like  **Class-Path**: libs/xyz.jar libs/abc.jar ...

Hope this process can resolve your "errorType": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"

Comment: It turns out that instead of manually doing this if you use the `maven-shade-plugin` everything gets done for you and you don't have to worry about it. At least, it worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: It didn't work. But, then after looking at your answer and poking around I was able to find the answer. Sorry for any problems.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782980/aws-lambda-noclassdeffounderror) I was able to find out about maven-shade-plugin which jarred everything together nicely and solved the problem.