# AmazonSNSClient noClassDefFound

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I am currently trying to get into coding against AWS and I ran into an issue when trying to subscribe a user to a SNS topic.

So what I have is a lambda expression that is supposed to take in an email and send that on to SNS. I can call the expression and that is working fine, but when it tries to create the `AmazonSNSClient` I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient`

The code is quite simple:

```
public String handleRequest(SubscriptionRequest request, Context context) {
    LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
    logger.log("Subscribing to list with email:" + request.email);
    logger.log("Creating SNS client");
    AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials());
    snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));
    //subscribe to an SNS topic
    SubscribeRequest subRequest = new SubscribeRequest(TOPIC_ARN, "email", request.email);
    logger.log("Sending request");
    snsClient.subscribe(subRequest);
    return "OK";
}
```

There are probably tons of other errors in it as well, but that is what I got so far, with the following dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.328</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.328</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.328</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I think that I have added more dependencies than I really need, but since I don't know where the issue is, I just tried adding anything that made some sort of sense.

So question is:

What am I missing, and what is causing the `NoClassDefFoundError`?

**edit**
Since the constructor for the `AmazonSNSClient` is deprecated I changed the line to

```
    logger.log("Creating SNS client");
    AmazonSNS snsClient = AmazonSNSClientBuilder.defaultClient();
```

But I still get errors with with it not finding the `AmazonSNSClientBuilder`.

It is almost as if it is not adding sns dependency to the jar file, which would be odd since the lambda dependency seems to be working fine

Answer (score 0):

found the solution here:
[AWS Lambda NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782980/aws-lambda-noclassdeffounderror)

had to make it into an uberjar with this piece of pom config

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```